# Bibtex puts wrong reference name

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, natbib

I'm using the style `plainnat` with the `beamer` class. I'm using BibTeX and this happens. I have the following in my `.bib`

```
@Article{ TiWuNg07,
    title = "{Performance analysis and improvement for BitTorrent-like file sharing systems}",
    author = "Y. Tian and Di Wu and KW Ng",
    journal = "Concurrency and Computation: Practice and Experience",
    volume = "19",
    number = "13",
    pages = "1811--1835",
    year = "2007",
    publisher = "John Wiley \& Sons"
}
```

And this is what appears as the `bibitem`:

```
\bibitem[Tian et~al.(2007)Tian, Wu, and Ng]{TiWuNg07}
Y.~Tian, Di~Wu, and KW~Ng.
\newblock {Performance analysis and improvement for BitTorrent-like file
  sharing systems}.
\newblock \emph{Concurrency and Computation: Practice and Experience},
  19\penalty0 (13):\penalty0 1811--1835, 2007.
```

Minimal code for `.tex`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,pdfpagelabels]{beamer}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{snapshot}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\setbeamercovered{transparent=100}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Warsaw}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\hypersetup{pdfnewwindow=true}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Tian, Wu, Ng - 2007\cite{TiWuNg07}}
\end{frame}
\section{Referencias}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Referencias}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{modelo}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The citation appears as `[Tian et~al.(2007)Tian, Wu, and Ng]` when it should be `[Tian et~al.(2007)]`

As you can see, in the citation text, the authors appear again after the year. Why is this happening and how can I solve it without changing it manually? All the other `bibitems` appear correctly.

Comment: I don't see the issue: in a quick test document the printed output looks fine. Perhaps a full minimal example and a mock-up of what you see and why it's wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What makes you think that the `plainnat` style will work without the `natbib` package? ;-)

Add the following to your preamble (the second code line will make `natbib` compatible with `beamer`):

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\newcommand*{\newblock}{}
```

and use `\citep` instead of `\cite` in the document.

Comment: That is a useful hack. Someone answered the same on an old question of mine about `beamer` and `natbib`. Sadly I had already accepted another answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the bibliography style `plainnat`, which is meant to be used with the `natbib` package, without actually loading this package. `natbib` stores some extra information, such as the author names and the year in the label. To get correct labels, either load `natbib`, or change the style to just `plain`.

Comment: Yes, but ... Simply loading `natbib` will result in an error message (because `\newblock` isn't defined in `beamer`).

Comment: @lockstep: Oh, I didn't know that (I never actually used bibtex in a `beamer` presentation). I guess that also `plain` would fail then, since it also puts the references inside `\newblock`:s. Seems like an odd omission in `beamer`.